# Sqlite database refresh in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Refresh the sqlite database. I have tried this code...

```
 if(sqlite3_exec(dataBase, "VACUUM;", 0, 0, NULL)==SQLITE_OK) 
    {      NSLog(@"Vacuumed DataBase");    

    }
```

My exact requirement is when i deleting some content then imediately refresh that sqlite not after kill the app....

I have used that code for refreshing the SQLITE But some differnt location not exactly after insert that means out of function.

this function will not execute. I want to refresh my Sqlite...

So how may I solve this issue please help me out this thanks in advance,.,,,

Comment: what you want to do in refresh :) you need to update the database

Comment: i just want to refresh because when i delete some content into sqlite and i want to new updated rowid.... thats why mr requirement is this.

Comment: "Refresh" is not a very good description of anything.  What is it you want to do?

Comment: (Understand the "VACUUM" does not have any effect on the visible data of the database, nor does it have any defined effect to, say, "force" the database to disk.  It merely compacts the database, to make the working size smaller.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the semicolon from your `"VACUUM;"` statement:

```
if (sqlite3_exec(dataBase, "VACUUM", 0, 0, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
   NSLog(@"Vacuumed DataBase");
}
```

I think the idea is that semicolon is a terminator only in the sqlite3 command line client, where it is required to inform the engine that your statement is complete. When using the C API, no terminator is required, because the full statement is received by `sqlite3_exec()`. Indeed, the semicolon is an error in this case. Go figure.

Also, you should handle the other SQLITE_XXX codes.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to:

- Update your database to change or delete data: use an SQL `UPDATE` statement.
- Check a function call: If a function in your code is not executed, check if it is inside the execution block of an if statement or if you call it at all.
- Reduce the size of your SQLite database file: use the `VACUUM` statement.

To execute any SQLite statement you have to prepare it. From the SQLite.org [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) about `sqlite_prepare`:

> To execute an SQL query, it must first be compiled into a byte-code program using one of these routines.

Comment: i used the vaccume but i want to call that vaccume in next button function imediately...

Comment: Well, in this case you need to do 2 things. First, call it in your button handler. Second, up-vote this answer and click the checkmark.